# How to select child in grid by column and row number

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

How can I locate an ui-element by Its location (row and column)?

Comment: Can you please post your calss definition code? It will very much help us help you.

Comment: Also indicate what structure did you use? Array, Custom?

Comment: The problem is that my code is in dutch. The point is just. I am using a grid of 7 by 7. every spot in that grid is filled with cells. those cells are also grids. when a player clicks in a cell an ellips that is part of the cell gets a red or a yellow colordepending by the player that clicked. What i want do to know is when the player has clicked the program checks first for a free row in the column that has been clicked starting from down to up. for every row in that column i want to check if there is a player selected or not. So basically i have the columnnumber and i want to select the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIElement FindByCell1(Grid g, int row, int col)
{
    var childs = g.Children.Cast<UIElement>()
    return childs.Where(x => Grid.GetRow(x) == row && Grid.GetColumn(x) == col).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If there may be some elements in the same cell:

```
IEnumerable<UIElement> FindByCell(Grid g, int row, int col)
{
    var childs = g.Children.Cast<UIElement>()
    return childs.Where(x => Grid.GetRow(x) == row && Grid.GetColumn(x) == col);
}
```

In your case, This way - working directly with the elements in the UI - its very very not recommended, and its the extreme opposite of MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer. My implementation (Generating array of Buttons in code then want indexed array thereof):

```
            Button[,] Buttons = new Button[8, endTimePlus1 - startTime];

        var buttons = controlGrid.Children.Cast<Button>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < endTimePlus1 - startTime; j++)
            {
                Buttons[i,j] =  buttons.Where(x => Grid.GetRow(x) == j && Grid.GetColumn(x) == i).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
```